# What permissions does the home directory need for ssh?

Tags: openssh

I have created several linux users with a home directory in a container and now I want to connect via ssh.

```
addgroup -S user1 && adduser -S user1 -G user1 -s /bin/sh
addgroup -S user2 && adduser -S user2 -G user2 -s /bin/sh
```

I then have the following directory structure in the container:

```
/home/
/home/user1/.ssh/
/home/user2/.ssh/
```

I noticed that the connection only works if the /home directory belongs to the respective user. Why is that?

```
ls -la /home
drwx------    1 user1    user1         37 Jun 23 09:25 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          92 Jun 23 12:17 ..
drwxr-sr-x    1 user1   user1          38 Jun 23 14:37 user1
drwxr-sr-x    1 user2   user2          38 Jun 23 14:43 user2
```

In this case I can log in via ssh as user1 without any problems. When logging in with user2 I get an error message - Permission denied (publickey).

If I now give the home directory to user2 instead of user1, I can log in with user2 but no longer with user1.

```
ls -la /home
drwx------    1 user2    user2         37 Jun 23 09:25 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          92 Jun 23 12:17 ..
drwxr-sr-x    1 user1   user1          38 Jun 23 14:37 user1
drwxr-sr-x    1 user2   user2          38 Jun 23 14:43 user2
```

How do I have to change my configuration so that I can log in with both users via ssh?

Comment: The `/home` directory shouldn't be owned by any "normal" user. No "normal" user should own the content of the other users. Instead it should be owned by `root` and the directory permissions should be something like `rwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by user Progman:

The /home directory shouldn't be owned by any "normal" user. No "normal" user should own the content of the other users. Instead it should be owned by root and the directory permissions should be something like rwxr-xr-x